# Clojure: Definitions of basic terms

Tags: clojure, terminology

In Clojure context,  some define the term *form* as “any valid code,” and some as “any valid code that returns a value.” So both the numeral `1729` and the string `Hello!` is a form. Likewise `(fn` is not a form. Is an undefined symbol, say `my-val`, a form?

What is the difference between an expression and a form?

What is the difference between an expression and a function?

Comment: Why do you think that `(fn ...` is not a form?

Comment: @OlegTheCat `(fn` is not a form in the same way as `"""` and `0_` aren’t forms in Clojure: for all of these the reader throws an exception. I think that is the point made in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good answers to this question at [Are Lisp forms and Lisp expressions same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206657/are-lisp-forms-and-lisp-expressions-same-thing)

The key thing to think about is that there are different points in the lifecycle. We start with text `"(+ 1 2)"` which is then [read](http://clojure.org/reference/reader) into Clojure data (a list containing a symbol and two numbers). Often in Lisps "expression" is used to mean the former and "form" is used to mean the latter. In practice, I do not find that people are at all consistent with this usage and often use both terms for both things.

If you take "form" to mean "something which can be evaluated", then `1729` or `"Hello!"` or the symbol `my-val` are all forms. When `my-val` is evaluated it is resolved in the current namespace, perhaps to a function instance, which is invokable. Functions are really important only at evaluation time, when they can be invoked.

Another interesting aspect are macros, which allow you to create new syntax. Note that macro expansion happens *after* reading though, which means that while you can create new syntax, it still must follow some basic expectations that are encoded into the reader (namely that invocations follow the pattern `(<invokable> <args...>)`). Note that macros work on read but unevaluated forms (data, not text) and must produce new forms.

Comment: yep, sorry - I think I deleted a couple lines by accident during the save.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between an expression and a form?

In my opinion `form` in a context of Clojure is something a compiler deals with. Some forms are valid expressions while others are "special" forms (i.e. macros).

> What is the difference between an expression and a function?

Any function is an expression.

> Is an undefined symbol, say my-val, a form?

I would say it is a valid expression (hence form) which yields to a compile time exception.

> Likewise `(fn)` is not a form

It seems like you are referring to some source, where this was declared, could you provide a link?

Comment: It is `(fn` not `(fn)`.

Comment: what is `(fn` ?

Comment: Not a valid form; is it not? If not, what is it that is not a valid form?

Comment: Any form (so are expressions) is a valid s-expression, right? So `(something` is not a valid s-expression, so it can't be a valid form. A compiler will tell you about this in some way.